# Finding a differential equation for a scalar field, given a stress energy tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

For a given scalar field $\phi$, the stress energy tensor is
\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial_{\nu}\phi - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial^{\alpha}\phi).
\end{equation}
How can I get a second order differential equation for $\phi$, assuming that the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ satisfies Einstein's equation?
I tried to use the identity $\nabla^{\mu}G_{\mu\nu}=0$, getting the following equation
\begin{equation}
0=\nabla^{\mu}T_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\rho}\nabla_{\rho}T_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\rho}(\partial_{\rho}T_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\rho\mu}T_{\alpha\nu}-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\nu\rho}T_{\mu\alpha}).
\end{equation}
But turns out that this is not a second order differential equation. How can I get such equation?

Comment: Are you sure this is the stress tensor you want to use?  Usually the stress tensor for a scalar field is quadratic in the field.  I would have expected the first term in your stress tensor to be $$\partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu\phi,$$ instead of $$\partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi.$$  In that case, you could get the field equation by just requiring that the stress tensor is divergence-free.

Comment: You're right, it's $\partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi$. That's what I've tried to do without any success.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:  It'll be easiest to just write the stress-energy tensor in terms of the covariant derivative (note that these are equivalent for scalar fields):
$$
T_{\mu \nu} = \nabla_\mu \phi \nabla_\nu \phi - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} \nabla^\rho \phi \nabla_\rho \phi
$$
Now take the divergence of $T_{\mu \nu}$ *without writing down any Christoffel symbols*;  leave all your derivatives in terms of $\nabla_\mu$, rather than $\partial_\mu$.  Use the facts that $\nabla_\mu$ obeys the product rule, and that by definition $\nabla_\mu g_{\rho \sigma} = 0$.

BTW, the assumption that $g_{\mu \nu}$ satisfies Einstein's equations is completely unnecessary for this derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you did does not provide a second order differential equation for $\phi$, since $T_{\mu\nu}$ is already second order in the derivatives.

The [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) of a matter sector is given by:
$$
T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}
$$

so we need to find an action $S_m=\int d^4x\,\sqrt{g}\,\mathcal{L}[\phi,\partial_\mu\phi]$ such that 
$$
T_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial_{\nu}\phi - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial^{\alpha}\phi)
$$
and since $\phi$ is scalar, and $T_{\mu\nu}$ is second order in the derivatives, we can easily conclude that:
$$
\mathcal{L}=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial_{\nu}\phi
$$

Now, you calculate the equations of motion for $\phi$:

$$
\frac{\delta S_m}{\delta \phi}=0
$$
that is:
$$
\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{g}\,\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)})=0
$$
a second order differential equation for $\phi$, for a given $g_{\mu\nu}$ determined.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Lagrangian formulation of RG. I've been told that one way to obtain the equation is by means of the Bianchi identities $\nabla_{[\mu}R_{\nu\gamma\delta]}=0$ and Einstein's equation.

Comment: I simply use the definition of $T_{\mu\nu}$. There is no mention to the lagragian of $g_{\mu\nu} $. Your proposal, of using $\nabla_{[\mu}R_{\nu\gamma]\delta\lambda}=0$ will not work. You are going to find the conservation of $T_{\mu\nu}$ again. See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) in the part of 'Features'/Comservation of energy and momentum

Comment: After the OP's edit, $T_{\mu \nu}$ only contains first derivatives of the scalar field, which means that requiring its divergence to be zero *will* result in a second-order differential equation in $\phi$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes, you are right.